# Java 11 HTTP API WebSocket client throws java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Tags: java, websocket, java-11

I'm switching from an undertow WebSocket client, which worked perfectly, to the [built-in implementation available from Java 11]. The connection with the WebSocket is successful, though, after the first message is sent, a SocketException is thrown because of a connection reset. As noted by the documentation, SocketExceptions are usually thrown because of an invalid protocol. Because of this, I tried to switch from TLSv1.3(theoretically the default in Java 11) to TLSv1.2, but this didn't solve the issue either. Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
    class WebSocketClient implements WebSocket.Listener {
        private void openConnection() {
            var sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
            sslContext.init(null, null, new SecureRandom());
            HttpClient.newBuilder()
                    .sslContext(sslContext)
                    .build()
                    .newWebSocketBuilder()
                    .header("Origin", "https://web.whatsapp.com")
                    .header("User-Agent", "some user agent")
                    .subprotocols("permessage-deflate", "client_max_window_bits")
                    .connectTimeout(Duration.of(30, ChronoUnit.SECONDS))
                    .buildAsync(URI.create("wss://web.whatsapp.com/ws"), this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onOpen(WebSocket socket) {
            WebSocket.Listener.super.onOpen(socket);
            socket.sendText("tag,irrelevantMessage", true);
        }
    }
```

I have enabled the debugging feature of the HTTP module and this is the output:

```
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [489ms] [WebSocket] RawChannelTube(SSLTube(SocketTube(1))) connectFlows
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [489ms] [WebSocket] RawChannelTube(SSLTube(SocketTube(1))) ReadSubscriber::onSubscribe
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [489ms] [WebSocket] RawChannelTube(SSLTube(SocketTube(1))) WritePublisher::subscribe
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [489ms] [WebSocket] RawChannelTube(SSLTube(SocketTube(1))) WriteSubscription::request 1
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [494ms] [Transport] write buffer capacity 16384
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [495ms] [WebSocket] signalOpen
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [495ms] [WebSocket] enter receive task
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [495ms] [WebSocket] receive state: OPEN
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [495ms] [WebSocket] enter onOpen 1
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [495ms] [WebSocket] request 1
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [502ms] [WebSocket] enter send text 1 payload length=124 last=true
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [502ms] [Transport] enter send text 1 message.length=124 last=true
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [502ms] [Transport] enter send task
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [502ms] [Transport] load message
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [502ms] [Output] encode text src=[pos=0 lim=124 cap=124] last=true dst=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=16384 cap=16384]
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [502ms] [Output] put
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [503ms] [Output] mask
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [503ms] [Output] moreText
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [503ms] [Output] frame #0
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [503ms] [Output] frame opcode=TEXT fin=true len=124
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [504ms] [Output] put
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [504ms] [Output] mask
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [504ms] [Output] moreText
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [504ms] [Transport] enter writing
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [504ms] [Transport] write state: UNREGISTERED
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [504ms] [Transport] registering write event
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [504ms] [WebSocket] RawChannelTube(SSLTube(SocketTube(1))) register write event
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [504ms] [Transport] write event
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [504ms] [Transport] registered write event
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [504ms] [Transport] exit writing
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [504ms] [Transport] exit send task
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [504ms] [Transport] enter send task
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [504ms] [Transport] 130 bytes remaining in buffer java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=130 cap=16384]
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [504ms] [Transport] enter writing
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [504ms] [Transport] write state: AVAILABLE
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [504ms] [Transport] writing to the channel
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [504ms] [WebSocket] RawChannelTube(SSLTube(SocketTube(1))) write: writing 130
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [505ms] [WebSocket] RawChannelTube(SSLTube(SocketTube(1))) WriteSubscription::request 1
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [505ms] [Transport] 130 bytes written
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [505ms] [Transport] finished writing to the channel
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [505ms] [Transport] exit writing
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [505ms] [Transport] removeAndComplete error=null
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [505ms] [Transport] exit send task
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [506ms] [Transport] exit send text 1 returned jdk.internal.net.http.common.MinimalFuture@5c97152e[Completed normally] (id=63)
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [506ms] [WebSocket] exit send text 1 returned jdk.internal.net.http.common.MinimalFuture@5c97152e[Completed normally] (id=63)
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [508ms] [WebSocket] exit onOpen 1
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [508ms] [WebSocket] change state from OPEN to IDLE true
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [508ms] [WebSocket] receive state: IDLE
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [508ms] [WebSocket] change state from IDLE to WAITING true
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [508ms] [Transport] request 1
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [508ms] [Transport] enter receive task
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [508ms] [Transport] receive state: UNREGISTERED
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [508ms] [WebSocket] RawChannelTube(SSLTube(SocketTube(1))) register read event
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [509ms] [WebSocket] RawChannelTube(SSLTube(SocketTube(1))) readSubscription: requesting 1
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [509ms] [Transport] exit receive task
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [509ms] [WebSocket] exit receive task
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [509ms] [WebSocket] enter receive task
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [509ms] [WebSocket] receive state: WAITING
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [509ms] [WebSocket] exit receive task
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [510ms] [WebSocket] RawChannelTube(SSLTube(SocketTube(1))) ReadSubscriber::onError java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.throwConnectionReset(SocketChannelImpl.java:394)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:426)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube.readAvailable(SocketTube.java:1162)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube$InternalReadPublisher$InternalReadSubscription.read(SocketTube.java:825)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube$SocketFlowTask.run(SocketTube.java:175)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$SchedulableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:198)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler.runOrSchedule(SequentialScheduler.java:271)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler.runOrSchedule(SequentialScheduler.java:224)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube$InternalReadPublisher$InternalReadSubscription.signalReadable(SocketTube.java:766)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube$InternalReadPublisher$ReadEvent.signalEvent(SocketTube.java:949)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube$SocketFlowEvent.handle(SocketTube.java:245)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl$SelectorManager.handleEvent(HttpClientImpl.java:960)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl$SelectorManager.lambda$run$3(HttpClientImpl.java:915)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl$SelectorManager.run(HttpClientImpl.java:915)
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [511ms] [WebSocket] RawChannelTube(SSLTube(SocketTube(1))) ReadSubscriber: handling event
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [511ms] [Transport] read event
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [511ms] [Transport] enter receive task
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [511ms] [Transport] receive state: AVAILABLE
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [511ms] [WebSocket] RawChannelTube(SSLTube(SocketTube(1))) read
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [511ms] [WebSocket] RawChannelTube(SSLTube(SocketTube(1))) read: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [511ms] [WebSocket] RawChannelTube(SSLTube(SocketTube(1))) shutdownInput
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [511ms] [WebSocket] signalError java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [511ms] [WebSocket] enter receive task
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [511ms] [WebSocket] receive state: ERROR
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [511ms] [WebSocket] processError
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [511ms] [Transport] closeInput
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [511ms] [WebSocket] enter onError 2 error=java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [511ms] [WebSocket] exit onError 2
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [511ms] [WebSocket] signalError java.lang.RuntimeException: An unhandled exception was registered during the lifecycle of this session
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [511ms] [WebSocket] signalError java.lang.RuntimeException: An unhandled exception was registered during the lifecycle of this session
java.lang.RuntimeException: An unhandled exception was registered during the lifecycle of this session
    at whatsapp4j/it.auties.whatsapp4j.whatsapp.WhatsappWebSocket.onError(WhatsappWebSocket.java:212)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.websocket.WebSocketImpl$ReceiveTask.processError(WebSocketImpl.java:500)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.websocket.WebSocketImpl$ReceiveTask.run(WebSocketImpl.java:454)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$CompleteRestartableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:147)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$SchedulableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:198)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler.runOrSchedule(SequentialScheduler.java:271)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler.runOrSchedule(SequentialScheduler.java:224)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.websocket.WebSocketImpl.trySetState(WebSocketImpl.java:837)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.websocket.WebSocketImpl.signalError(WebSocketImpl.java:714)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.websocket.WebSocketImpl$SignallingMessageConsumer.onError(WebSocketImpl.java:825)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.websocket.TransportImpl$ReceiveTask.run(TransportImpl.java:704)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$CompleteRestartableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:147)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$SchedulableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:198)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler.runOrSchedule(SequentialScheduler.java:271)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler.runOrSchedule(SequentialScheduler.java:224)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.websocket.TransportImpl$ReadEvent.handle(TransportImpl.java:766)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.RawChannelTube$ReadSubscriber.checkEvents(RawChannelTube.java:174)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.RawChannelTube$ReadSubscriber.onError(RawChannelTube.java:212)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLTube$DelegateWrapper.onError(SSLTube.java:257)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLTube$SSLSubscriberWrapper.complete(SSLTube.java:441)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLTube$SSLSubscriberWrapper.onErrorImpl(SSLTube.java:511)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLTube$SSLSubscriberWrapper.onError(SSLTube.java:525)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SubscriberWrapper$DownstreamPusher.run1(SubscriberWrapper.java:294)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SubscriberWrapper$DownstreamPusher.run(SubscriberWrapper.java:259)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$SynchronizedRestartableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:175)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$CompleteRestartableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:147)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$SchedulableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:198)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler.runOrSchedule(SequentialScheduler.java:271)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler.runOrSchedule(SequentialScheduler.java:224)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SubscriberWrapper.errorCommon(SubscriberWrapper.java:419)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Reader.errorCommon(SSLFlowDelegate.java:366)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SubscriberWrapper.onError(SubscriberWrapper.java:410)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube$InternalReadPublisher$ReadSubscription.signalCompletion(SocketTube.java:629)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube$InternalReadPublisher$InternalReadSubscription.read(SocketTube.java:813)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube$SocketFlowTask.run(SocketTube.java:175)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$SchedulableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:198)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler.runOrSchedule(SequentialScheduler.java:271)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler.runOrSchedule(SequentialScheduler.java:224)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube$InternalReadPublisher$InternalReadSubscription.signalReadable(SocketTube.java:766)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube$InternalReadPublisher$ReadEvent.signalEvent(SocketTube.java:949)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube$SocketFlowEvent.handle(SocketTube.java:245)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl$SelectorManager.handleEvent(HttpClientImpl.java:960)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl$SelectorManager.lambda$run$3(HttpClientImpl.java:915)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl$SelectorManager.run(HttpClientImpl.java:915)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.throwConnectionReset(SocketChannelImpl.java:394)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:426)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube.readAvailable(SocketTube.java:1162)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube$InternalReadPublisher$InternalReadSubscription.read(SocketTube.java:825)
    ... 11 more
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [512ms] [WebSocket] exit receive task
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [512ms] [WebSocket] set state ERROR (previous WAITING) true
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [512ms] [WebSocket] close
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [512ms] [Transport] closeInput
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [512ms] [Transport] closeOutput
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [512ms] [WebSocket] RawChannelTube(SSLTube(SocketTube(1))) shutdownOutput
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [512ms] [WebSocket] RawChannelTube(SSLTube(SocketTube(1))) close
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [512ms] [Transport] enter send task
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [512ms] [Transport] exit send task
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [512ms] [Transport] exit receive task
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-SelectorManager] [512ms] [WebSocket] RawChannelTube(SSLTube(SocketTube(1))) WriteSubscription::cancel
```

Update:

As suggested in the comments, I've modified my code and now the exception's message is "Connection reset by peer" instead of "Connection reset". These are the new logs:

```
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [333ms] [WebSocket] RawChannelTube(SSLTube(SocketTube(1))) connectFlows
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [333ms] [WebSocket] RawChannelTube(SSLTube(SocketTube(1))) ReadSubscriber::onSubscribe
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [333ms] [WebSocket] RawChannelTube(SSLTube(SocketTube(1))) WritePublisher::subscribe
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [333ms] [WebSocket] RawChannelTube(SSLTube(SocketTube(1))) WriteSubscription::request 1
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [336ms] [Transport] write buffer capacity 16384
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [337ms] [WebSocket] signalOpen
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [337ms] [WebSocket] enter receive task
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [337ms] [WebSocket] receive state: OPEN
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [338ms] [WebSocket] enter onOpen 1
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [338ms] [WebSocket] request 1
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [338ms] [WebSocket] exit onOpen 1
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [338ms] [WebSocket] change state from OPEN to IDLE true
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [338ms] [WebSocket] receive state: IDLE
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [338ms] [WebSocket] change state from IDLE to WAITING true
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [338ms] [Transport] request 1
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [338ms] [Transport] enter receive task
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [338ms] [Transport] receive state: UNREGISTERED
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [338ms] [WebSocket] RawChannelTube(SSLTube(SocketTube(1))) register read event
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [338ms] [WebSocket] RawChannelTube(SSLTube(SocketTube(1))) readSubscription: requesting 1
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [338ms] [Transport] exit receive task
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [338ms] [WebSocket] exit receive task
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [338ms] [WebSocket] enter receive task
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [338ms] [WebSocket] receive state: WAITING
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [338ms] [WebSocket] exit receive task
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [339ms] [WebSocket] enter send binary 1 payload=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=0 cap=0] last=true
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [339ms] [Transport] enter send binary 1 message.remaining=0 last=true
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [339ms] [Transport] enter send task
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [339ms] [Transport] load message
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [339ms] [Output] encode binary src=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=0 cap=0] last=true dst=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=16384 cap=16384]
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [340ms] [Output] frame opcode=BINARY fin=true len=0
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [340ms] [Transport] enter writing
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [340ms] [Transport] write state: UNREGISTERED
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [340ms] [Transport] registering write event
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [340ms] [WebSocket] RawChannelTube(SSLTube(SocketTube(1))) register write event
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [340ms] [Transport] write event
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [340ms] [Transport] registered write event
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [340ms] [Transport] exit writing
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [340ms] [Transport] exit send task
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [340ms] [Transport] enter send task
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [340ms] [Transport] 6 bytes remaining in buffer java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=6 cap=16384]
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [340ms] [Transport] enter writing
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [340ms] [Transport] write state: AVAILABLE
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [340ms] [Transport] writing to the channel
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [340ms] [WebSocket] RawChannelTube(SSLTube(SocketTube(1))) write: writing 6
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [340ms] [WebSocket] RawChannelTube(SSLTube(SocketTube(1))) WriteSubscription::request 1
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [341ms] [Transport] 6 bytes written
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [341ms] [Transport] finished writing to the channel
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [341ms] [Transport] exit writing
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [341ms] [Transport] removeAndComplete error=null
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [341ms] [Transport] exit send task
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [342ms] [Transport] exit send binary 1 returned jdk.internal.net.http.common.MinimalFuture@2750fa5d[Completed normally] (id=64)
DEBUG: [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] [342ms] [WebSocket] exit send binary 1 returned jdk.internal.net.http.common.MinimalFuture@2750fa5d[Completed normally] (id=64)
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-0] [344ms] [WebSocket] RawChannelTube(SSLTube(SocketTube(1))) WriteSubscription::cancel
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-0] [344ms] [WebSocket] RawChannelTube(SSLTube(SocketTube(1))) shutdownOutput
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-0] [345ms] [WebSocket] RawChannelTube(SSLTube(SocketTube(1))) ReadSubscriber::onError java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev(SocketDispatcher.java:58)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:182)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:130)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:563)
    at java.base/java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.write(SocketChannel.java:642)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube.writeAvailable(SocketTube.java:1228)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube$InternalWriteSubscriber.tryFlushCurrent(SocketTube.java:342)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube$InternalWriteSubscriber.onNext(SocketTube.java:309)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube.onNext(SocketTube.java:133)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube.onNext(SocketTube.java:56)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SubscriberWrapper$DownstreamPusher.run1(SubscriberWrapper.java:316)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SubscriberWrapper$DownstreamPusher.run(SubscriberWrapper.java:259)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$SynchronizedRestartableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:175)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$CompleteRestartableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:147)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$SchedulableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:198)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler.runOrSchedule(SequentialScheduler.java:271)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler.runOrSchedule(SequentialScheduler.java:224)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SubscriberWrapper.outgoing(SubscriberWrapper.java:232)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SubscriberWrapper.outgoing(SubscriberWrapper.java:198)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Writer.sendResultBytes(SSLFlowDelegate.java:934)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Writer.processData(SSLFlowDelegate.java:817)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Writer$WriterDownstreamPusher.run(SSLFlowDelegate.java:694)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$CompleteRestartableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:147)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$SchedulableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:198)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler.runOrSchedule(SequentialScheduler.java:271)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler.runOrSchedule(SequentialScheduler.java:224)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Writer.triggerWrite(SSLFlowDelegate.java:771)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate.doHandshake(SSLFlowDelegate.java:1083)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate.doClosure(SSLFlowDelegate.java:1169)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Reader.unwrapBuffer(SSLFlowDelegate.java:549)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Reader.processData(SSLFlowDelegate.java:433)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Reader$ReaderDownstreamPusher.run(SSLFlowDelegate.java:268)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$SynchronizedRestartableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:175)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$CompleteRestartableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:147)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$SchedulableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:198)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-0] [345ms] [WebSocket] RawChannelTube(SSLTube(SocketTube(1))) ReadSubscriber: handling event
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-0] [345ms] [Transport] read event
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-0] [345ms] [Transport] enter receive task
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-0] [345ms] [Transport] receive state: AVAILABLE
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-0] [345ms] [WebSocket] RawChannelTube(SSLTube(SocketTube(1))) read
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-0] [345ms] [WebSocket] RawChannelTube(SSLTube(SocketTube(1))) read: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-0] [345ms] [WebSocket] RawChannelTube(SSLTube(SocketTube(1))) shutdownInput
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-0] [346ms] [WebSocket] signalError java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-0] [346ms] [WebSocket] enter receive task
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-0] [346ms] [WebSocket] receive state: ERROR
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-0] [346ms] [WebSocket] processError
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-0] [346ms] [Transport] closeInput
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-0] [346ms] [WebSocket] enter onError 2 error=java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
DEBUG: [HttpClient-1-Worker-0] [346ms] [WebSocket] exit onError 2
```

I've also reproduced the same piece of code using JakartaEE 9.1 and it seems to work perfectly

```
@ClientEndpoint(configurator = ClientTest.class)
public class ClientTest extends ClientEndpointConfig.Configurator {
    public void openConnection() throws DeploymentException, IOException {
        var session = createSession();
        session.getBasicRemote().sendText("tag,irrelevantMessage");
    }

    private Session createSession() throws DeploymentException, IOException {
        return ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer().connectToServer(this, URI.create("wss://web.whatsapp.com/ws"));
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onTextMessage(String message){
        System.out.println(message);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeRequest(Map<String, List<String>> headers) {
        headers.put("Origin", List.of("https://web.whatsapp.com"));
    }
}
```

Even sending an empty binary message will throw an equivalent exception

Comment: Is there an error on the code you pasted or are you really ignoring the value returned by `HttpClient.newBuilder().sslContext(sslContext).build().newWebSocketBuilder()...` ?

Comment: @daniel i'm ignoring it as the same instance is passed also to the onOpen method

Comment: This is a suspicion - but ignoring the result could mean the HttpClient is temporarily no longer referenced during the time it takes to build the websocket and the time onOpen is invoked. This could cause the HttpClient to start its shutdown sequence as soon as the websocket is created since no strong reference exists. Could you try to modify your code to store the result of the call in an instance variable in your WebSocketClient class - and see if it changes anything?

Comment: @daniel the error wasn't fixed, though a different exception is thrown java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer. I've noticed that Java11's WebSocket uses UTF16 to encode text, isn't it possible that the server doesn't support said encoding?

Comment: As far as I can see the text is sent with UTF-8 encoding - not UTF-16.

Comment: I did some research - the WebSocket and HttpClient should stay open until the websocket gets closed. So my suspicion appears to have been unfounded. "Connection Reset" - or "Connection reset by peer" - means that the underlying TCP connection was closed while there was still unsent/unread data in the socket buffers - which fueled my original suspicion.

Comment: I'm starting to wonder whether this is a bug in the JDK. It looks very suspicious that an equivalent piece of code written using JakartaEE's API works flawlessly

Comment: And I think you are right - what is happening here is that the server is closing the connection.

Answer (score 1):

Please try without the timeout parameter `.connectTimeout(Duration.of(30, ChronoUnit.SECONDS))` ...

```
class WebSocketClient implements WebSocket.Listener {
    private void openConnection() {
        var sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
        sslContext.init(null, null, new SecureRandom());
        HttpClient.newBuilder()
                .sslContext(sslContext)
                .build()
                .newWebSocketBuilder()
                .header("Origin", "https://web.whatsapp.com")
                .header("User-Agent", "some user agent")
                .subprotocols("permessage-deflate", "client_max_window_bits")
                .buildAsync(URI.create("wss://web.whatsapp.com/ws"), this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onOpen(WebSocket socket) {
        WebSocket.Listener.super.onOpen(socket);
        socket.sendText("tag,irrelevantMessage", true);
    }
}
```

Comment: how come done opt to go the native wat than to use libs as much ?